# Turn <class 'str> throws error when put in list

Tags: python, selenium

I'm currently working on a youtube webscraper for comments.

I want to scape the comments and put them in a dataframe. My code can only print the text but I'm unable to put the text into a dataframe. When I check the output's type, it is a ' <class 'str'> ' I'm able to get the text through this code:

```
    try:
        # Extract the elements storing the usernames and comments.
        username_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="author-text"]')
        comment_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-text"]')       
    except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        error = "Error: Double check selector OR "
        error += "element may not yet be on the screen at the time of the find operation"
        print(error)
    for com_text in comment_elems:
        print(com_text.text)
```

If I check the text through this code at the end of my function.

```
    for com_text in comment_elems:
        print(type(com_text.text)
```

then the result is <class 'str'>. And then I am unable to put this in a dataframe.

When I do try to put this <class 'str'> object in a dataframe, I get the error: ***TypeError: 'WebElement' object does not support item assignment***

This is the code that I use when trying to put the text in a dataframe:

```
    for username, comment in zip(username_elems, comment_elems):
        comment_section['comment'] = comment.text
        data.append(comment_section)
```

I'm hoping there is a way to convert the <class 'str'> object into a regular string type or if there is another step I can take to extract the text from the object.

***Here is my full code***

```
def gitscrape(url):
    # Note: replace argument with absolute path to the driver executable.
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver/windows/chromedriver.exe')

    # Navigates to the URL, maximizes the current window, and
    # then suspends execution for (at least) 5 seconds (this gives time for the page to load).
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(5)
    
    #empty subjects
    comment_section =[]
    comment_data = []
    
    try:
        # Extract the elements storing the video title and
        # comment section.
        title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/h1/yt-formatted-string').text
        comment_section = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="comments"]')
    except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        # Note: Youtube may have changed their HTML layouts for videos, so raise an error for sanity sake in case the
        # elements provided cannot be found anymore.
        error = "Error: Double check selector OR "
        error += "element may not yet be on the screen at the time of the find operation"
        print(error)

    # Scroll into view the comment section, then allow some time
    # for everything to be loaded as necessary.
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", comment_section)
    time.sleep(7)

    # Scroll all the way down to the bottom in order to get all the
    # elements loaded (since Youtube dynamically loads them).
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")

    while True:
        # Scroll down 'til "next load".
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load everything thus far.
        time.sleep(2)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height.
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height

    # One last scroll just in case.
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")

    try:
        # Extract the elements storing the usernames and comments.
        username_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="author-text"]')
        comment_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-text"]')       
    except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        error = "Error: Double check selector OR "
        error += "element may not yet be on the screen at the time of the find operation"
        print(error)
        
#     for com_text in comment_elems:
#         print(type(com_text.text)
#         data.append(comment_section)

    for username, comment in zip(username_elems, comment_elems):
        comment_section['comment'] = comment.text
        data.append(comment_section)
        
    video1_comments = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: `<class 'str'>` indicates a normal string, so the error must lie when trying to put your string into a dataframe. Can you show code that reproduces your erro?

Comment: @syntonym thank you for the clarification! just added the code to the question

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet that I can run that reproduces the error you're facing? I have the suspicion that `comment_section` or `comment_section['comment']` is not what you think it is, but I cannot check this.

Comment: @syntonym added my full code! thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

<class 'str'> is used to represent normal strings in Python. In the code below both print statements print out <class 'str'>. You must be facing a different issue.

```
a = 12345
a = str(a)
print(type(a))
b = "12345"
print(type(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error occurs in the line `comment_section['comment'] = comment.text`. You write in your text that you encounter that error when you try to put a string into a dataframe, but neither `comment_section` nor `comment` is a dataframe. In your title you write that adding a string to a list which throws an error, but `comment_section` is also not a list (and if it where, the syntax wouldn't make any sense). Coding is very sensitive to what you're actually doing, so having a dataframe or a list makes a big difference.

What is `comment_section` actually for a type? If you scroll up throw your code the last assignment is the following: `comment_section = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="comments"]')` so `comment_section` is actually neither a dataframe nor a list, but a webelement! Now the error you got also makes sense, it says `TypeError: 'WebElement' object does not support item assignment` and indeed you're trying to assign `comment.text` to the `comment` key of the WebElement `comment_section`, but the WebElement does not support this.

You can repair this by not overwriting `comment_sectin` but by using a different name.